# Splitting strings in an array - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with an array variable that's currently made up of a two part string as in the example below.  The first part is a datetime and the second part is a price.  Records in the dataframe have different length price_trend arrays.

```
Id  Name    Color    price_trend                
1   apple   red      '1420848000:1.25', '1440201600:1.35', '1443830400:1.52'                 60
2   lemon   yellow   '1403740800:0.32','1422057600:0.25'
```

I'd like to split each of the strings in the array into two parts around the colon (:), however when I run the code below, all the values in price_trend are replaced with nan

```
df['price_trend'] = df['price_trend'].str.split(':')
```

I would like to keep the array in this dataframe, and not a create a new one.

Comment: I haven't used pandas, but `split` will return a list because you're turning the string into two numbers. Do you want both numbers? What should happen with the two of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['price_trend'].apply(lambda x:[i.split(':') for i in x])`

```
0    [['1420848000, 1.25'], [ '1440201600, 1.35'], [ '1443830400, 1.52']]
1                            [['1403740800, 0.32'], ['1422057600, 0.25']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume below code should work for you

```
>>> df={}
>>> df['p']=['1420848000:1.25', '1440201600:1.35', '1443830400:1.52']
>>> df['p']=[ x.split(':') for x in df['p']]
>>> df
{'p': [['1420848000', '1.25'], ['1440201600', '1.35'], ['1443830400', '1.52']]}
```